# Latest time to say Maariv

Tags: halacha, tefilla, time, maariv

When is the latest time one can daven Maariv/Arvit? Is there a divergence between the letter of the law and an ideal time (לכתחילה/בדיעבד)?

Answer (score 7):

One can pray until dawn (*alot hashahar*), ideally (*lechathila*) one should do so before midnight (halachic midnight i.e., *hatzot*) ([Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 70:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.70.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Chabad.org [explains](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/649173/jewish/When-is-the-latest-I-can-say-the-evening-prayers.htm)

> The time for reciting maariv (the evening prayers) extends throughout
>   the night. Nevertheless, the sages were concerned that people would
>   delay the recitation of the biblically mandated nighttime Shema –
>   which is recited as part of the maariv – until the last moment, and
>   risk forgetting to say it altogether. They therefore instituted that
>   maariv should be prayed before halachic midnight. If this time has passed, one can still pray the complete maariv until
>   alot hashachar (dawn).
>
> If due to unavoidable circumstances alot hashachar has arrived and you
>   have not yet prayed maariv, you may still do so until sunrise.
>   However, omit the blessing beginning with the words "Hashkiveinu
>   avinu" ("Our Father, lie us down..."). In this blessing we ask G‑d to
>   give us a peaceful night, and it would be somewhat silly to request a
>   good night when the day is just beginning!

A practical calendar to see what times this corresponds to in your location can be found [here](http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/month_cdo/jewish/Jewish-Calendar.htm).

Comment: That's shema, what any amidah

Answer (score 0):

[The first chapter in Mishnah Brachos](http://emishnah.com/PDFs/Berakhot01.pdf) discusses the latest time one can daven Maariv. The halacha is that you may daven Maariv from when the stars come out (tzeis hakochavim) until sunrise, and this is brought from a story of Rabban Gamliel's sons returning home late from a feast.

Comment: What do you mean by "Maariv"?

Comment: That Mishna specifies the latest time to say the Shema. Does the same ruling also apply for Amida of Arvit?

Comment: @ElShteiger - [It seems to apply to Maariv as well.](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3260)

Comment: AFAIR, there is a discrepancy between the biblical/rabbinical obligation and I'd like to know what the pragmatic Halachic conclusion is

Comment: @ElSteiger - There is no biblical obligation to recite Maariv.

Comment: @ezra It's generally not accepted that you can say everything until sunrise. Moreover this answer doesn't address what is the ideal final time as the question sought. Indeed that link you cite clearly provides a different answer than your post here!!

Comment: @ElShteiger There’s technically not even a Rabbinic obligation to recite Maariv. It has become Halacha because it has been universally accepted to be treated as Halacha rather than Minhag. Shema is, of course, Biblical; this comment refers to Shemoneh Esrei.

Comment: The Mishna is about kriat shema.an other Mishna says תפילת הערב, אין לה קבע.   Bartenura   זמנה כל הלילה